# SQL Server 2008 tables name problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Could you tell me how to remove the database name from the table's name.

Each time I create a table the database name is automatically prefixed to the name

this is my table definition

```
Create table Links
(
Id Int IDEntity(1,1) ,
DisplayName Varchar(250) NOT NULL,
Href Varchar(250) NOT NULL,
Tooltip Varchar(550) NOT NULL,
IsVisible smallInt,
[Index] int,
IsEditable smallInt,
IsOnMenu smallInt 
)
```

thanks

Comment: A table in SQL Server is **always** part of a **schema** - typically `dbo.` - and that's a good thing, you can't "remove" that from the table (nor should you want to).

Comment: Actually, always **adding** the `dbo.` schema prefix to your database objects is a good thing - it will speed up your queries just a tad, and make things generally more explicit and clear.

Comment: And stop using reserved words for field or table names. Index is a horrible name for a field.  And in general you will find reporting is much harder if you use ID as the name of the id field. Use tablename ID and life will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database name or `schema` name?  what happens when you do this?

```
 Create table BlaTest(id int)

 Insert BlaTest values(1)

 select * from BlaTest
```

What do you see?

Also can you run this after you have run the script above and post results

```
select *
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME = 'BlaTest'
```

or for your table

```
select *
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME = 'Links'
```

you can't remove the schema..a table is always part of a schema...you don't have to use the name and then it will assume the default schema for the user that is executing the query. However if you do include the schema then SQL Server does not have to lookup the schema every time and you get a little performance benefit

Comment: you are right i think its the  schema name but how do iremove it?nk is th thi

Comment: you can't remove it..a table is always part of a schema...you don't have to use the name and then it will assume the default schema for the user that is executing the query

Comment: @GigaPr: why do you even want to remove it?? This cannot be done - a table is **always** part of a schema - you cannot have tables "floating around" outside of any schema.